# How to determine the IP of an edge node that submitted a job to a Hadoop Cluster

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

How can I determine the IP of the edge node that submitted a job to my through the Hadoop Web UI?

Answer (score 0):

On the jobtracker web UI, if you click on the jobid, you should see values for "*Submit Host Address*", which is the IP address of the host where the job was submitted.